# How to use Wicket to render html without a servlet engine or web.xml?

Tags: java, servlets, wicket

I need to create a bunch of html mails with Wicket. But afaik Wicket requires a servlet context.

So I'm looking for a way to use Wicket as a simple renderer for html. That is, render my `Page` objects, without having to start up a servlet engine.

In essence:

```
 String renderPageToHtml (Page page) { 
     /* 
        1. Instantiate wicket. 
        2. Render page to String
        3. Return it.
      */
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068429/wicket-how-to-render-page-programmatically-and-get-result-as-string/7069115#7069115

Answer (score 5):

Not tested it, but you might try the [WicketTester](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/WicketTester.html). This class is actually for resting, but allows to instantiate Components without a servlet container.

```
WicketTester tester = new WicketTester(new MyApplication();
tester.startPage(MyPage.class);
String MyPageAsString = tester.getLastResponseAsString();
```

As I said, use at your own risk, I have not tested this.